# Unreported 400 Bad Request Errors

Tags: apache-2.4

The following two `curl` commands trigger `400 Bad Request` errors which don't appear in the `ErrorLog` and aren't handled by the custom `ErrorDocument`

```
curl localhost -H ";"

> 400 Bad Request
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

This one is slightly different:

```
curl localhost -H "Host;"

> 400 Bad Request
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
> Additionallyt, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Apache configuration:

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache.log
LogLevel notice

ErrorDocument 400 /errHandler
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly where in your Apache configuration does this `ErrorLog` directive  appear?

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually setting `LogLevel` to `debug` shows an error about "malformed request" but I'm more worried about it not being handled by the designated `ErrorDocument`

Comment: I'm not sure you would want to anyway. If the Host header is malformed then you can't trust any other part of the request, and running a script could be dangerous. It's 2020. The only reasons for the Host header to be missing are: malware, a very poorly coded HTTP client, or someone trying to run ancient software from the early 1990s. It doesn't make sense to do anything but return a generic error to any of these cases.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm aware of that and that's the reason I want to know about malformed requests, maybe to at least block the source, but the way it is right now is that apache isn't giving me the chance to.

Comment: Are you actually being overwhelmed with such requests? These are normally exceedingly rare, except in the case of malware, where they're merely uncommon. And anyway, fail2ban can certainly take care of banning such requests if it's really necessary.

Comment: No I was just testing, I also went to check the apache source code because it wasn't obvious to me that not all errors are handled by their respective `ErrorDocument` - and thanks for your suggestion @MichaelHampton